# Blender Video Sequence Editor select all strips to the right and left don't have shortcuts in User Perferences

Tags: video-sequence-editor, shortcut

I can't find any shortcuts defined under user preferences for these two actions.

I tried searching for things like "right" in the input configuration, and I also tried looking through all the shortcuts under sequencer.

Why are these shortcuts not listed?  I know I can change the shortcuts by right clicking the menu option but I expected to find them in user preferences.

Comment: Okay I figured it out.  It's called "Activate/Select".  Man that was confusing.  I found it by assigning it a hotkey and then searching for the new shortcut.  I have another question now.  How do I find out if a shortcut is already used?  Is the best way to search for the shortcut in user preferences?  It would be great if there was a warning before assigning it via right click on the menu option.  Especially in cases like these where it's not obvious which shortcut will be changed and it saves a few steps of searching and opening user preferences.

Comment: Blender keymapping mechanism although very powerful is very limited in debugging area. There is currently no mechanism in place for detecting conflicts and assigned hotkeys beyond manualy searching.